# ES query for huge set of records gives Out Of Memory error

Tags: elasticsearch, out-of-memory

In my application, I have huge set of records in ES. I am querying 500000 records and writing to a file, it is working fine. After the file has been generated, I tried the same query. But the memory is not released because of the first query, so I am getting out of memory error.

I have below questions as part of the current scenario:

1. What kind of query should I use for large set of queries. Currently I am using boolean query and also springESTemplate.
2. How to release memory after executing query

Comment: Please give a bit more information about the structure of the data and the executed query. Is the out of memory coming from elastic search or does it happen in your application.

Comment: not form elasticsearch server. It is happening in my application only.

Comment: we have a query to fetch the records and write to a file with a record limit of 500000. i am not sure how to set size incase of spring elastic search. coz limit filter applies per shard concept.

Comment: When using java, what kind of client do you use?

Comment: TransportClient. I am using Spring es template instead of using client directly

Comment: I am afraid this is a spring/data/elasticsearch problem. Maybe if you provide some code that someone can spot a problem. I am not that familiar with spring/elasticsearch integreation. Never use it. It does not feel as an elasticsearch problem.

Comment: Out of memory error due to large volume of data being bold in byte array output stream in order to write into file. I have a work around for it. But i have a question in elastic search query limit. i am having 5 shards. how can i limit the results to 43 records using pagerequest.